# Is it possible to run ES index without refresh interval?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I’m running ElasticSearch  application locally on docker container to index 10M docs per day (to one index).
Let’s assume that I send the data in optimal bulk request,As I know, we have 2 process which related to the indexing (refresh - which make the data available NRR, and sync which flush the trans log to disk) , it feels that the operation do the same thing and because I have only 1 aggressive operation in a day the question is if I can work without refresh and what the down side (in my case and in distributed cases with similar tasks - 1 massive indexing operation per day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run elasticsearch without refresh interval by setting

```
"index" : {
    "refresh_interval" : -1
}
```

And then run indexing of your new documents manually using **refresh** query parameter at your request.

And im pretty sure that if you have 1 aggressive indexing operation per day - that may work. Especially if no one searches the data while you are indexing data.
Because for sure it will consume huge amount of RAM while operating 10M docs. That basically means that searching speed will be drastically reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh and synced flush are two differen, yet complimentary operations that go hand in hand.

What refresh does is to update the **in-memory** index to make sure that the data you've just indexed is now searchable.

All indexing operations are also written to the transaction log but are not committed to Lucene on every individual change because Lucene commits are too expensive to perform.

What a synced flush does is to commit the content of the transaction log to Lucene and start a new transaction log generation.

So to summarize, you need **both refresh and flush** to happen in order for your data to be searchable and safely committed to Lucene.

[Refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) is a pretty lightweight operation that runs every second (by default).

[Flush](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-flush.html) is a more expensive operation that runs every 5 seconds to make sure the transaction log doesn't grow too big.

If you are only loading a single batch of data every day, you can definitely call the Refresh API and the Flush API right after to make sure all your data is searchable and safe.
You can definitely run it just after indexing your daily batch of data.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, but is the refresh save more data, or when I send query to ES, it goes to Lucene index or to the “cache” which generated by refresh operation?

Comment: The Lucene index is stored on disk and loaded into memory during searches. A search is always ran against the in-memory index. I'm still not sure what problem you're trying to solve... seems like a non-issue to me

Comment: I want to understand what the consequences of removing the refresh operation to reduce overhead of the refresh . But it looks like the best solution is to refresh once a day after the indexing… thank you..

Comment: Yes, you can disable refresh before starting your bulk indexing, then send all your data and then re-enable the refresh when all your data has been indexed. I think I misunderstood your initial question, where I thought you wanted to completely disable refresh because you felt it was redundant.